# creating a new branch in git with one commit omitted

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in my project branch1 and branch2.

This is the order of commits on the branches.

output of git log on branch1:

```
commit 'a'
commit 'b'
commit 'c'
commit 'd'
```

output of git log on branch2:

```
commit 'f'
commit 'e'
commit 'c' 
commit 'd'
```

and I would like to create a new branch which in sync with branch1 and also have the changes that are in just commit 'f'.

so the new branch commits should look like this

```
commit 'f'
commit 'a'
commit 'b'
commit 'c'
commit 'd'
```

How to proceed with this one?

Comment: Is the newest commit at the top or the bottom?

Comment: newest commit is at top. for branch 1, newest commit is 'a'.

Comment: then forivall's solution is just right (starting from branch1)

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout -b [new branch name]
git cherry-pick [hash of commit 'f']
```